# Stacked Bar Chart Giving Strange Results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display some data in stacked bar chart, as I have a lot of data to display on certain dates, split out by regions for a single product.  However, when I set the

```
aes(y=ProductID, x=Date, fill=region)
```

my ProductID seems to be summed or something, because my count is super high.  My dataframe contains ~3000 rows, but the count (y axis) is upwards of 40,000.

I was able to solve this by adding a helper column of 1s, and set this to as my `y`, but even when I tried to set the `y=nrows(dataframe)` I was still getting an incredibly high count on the bar chart.

Is there something special about `geom_bar(stat='identity')` that is throwing this for a loop?

Comment: It would help to have some sample data?

Comment: So x is the position of the bar, and y is the height of the bar (if stat="identity"). Is that what you intend? You are using the ProductID as the height of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to count ProductID for each Date. How about a facet by region?

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(ProductID=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1000,TRUE),
                   Date=sample(2000:2019, 1000, TRUE),
                   region=sample(c("Here", "There", "Elsewhere"), 100, TRUE))

ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data=data, mapping=aes(x=Date, fill=ProductID)) +
    facet_wrap(~region, nrow=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks...my mistake was not realizing that `aes(fill = productId)` or in my case i wanted region as the fill to show all in one chart, would result in the same stacked chart.  Basically i didn't need to use the `stat = 'identity'` to get the result I was looking for.  However, after playing with it a while, I had to group the dates a little more because I had too many individual days, so after grouping it into months, I had x = date, y = total (from each date), fill = region, and I then I had to use `stat = 'identity'` to get the result I was looking for.

Comment: You could probably get ggplot to do the stats for you, rather than use stat="identity". The default stat is "count" which counts the rows, and then you don't supply a y aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, ggplot2 bar chart make chart of count for x value, so you don't need to input y value. In case you need many categorical variables, used other method as color, fill or facet.